# Dependency Injection Does not work in Models or Tests in Play Framework 2.4.x

Tags: java, unit-testing, playframework, dependency-injection

I am trying to write some unit tests for my Play Framework 2.4.6 application. I need WS for my purposes testing. However, when I used the documention's method to inject WS I end up with a null pointer if used in a test or a model. However, the injection works perfectly if I install it into one of my controllers.

Here is my test:

```
import org.junit.Test;
import play.test.WithServer;
import play.libs.ws.*;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import static play.test.Helpers.running;
import static play.test.Helpers.testServer;

public class UserProfileTests extends WithServer {
    @Inject
    WSClient ws;

    @Test
    public void demographicTest() {

        System.out.println(ws.toString()); //null pointer exception

        running(testServer(3333), () -> {
            System.out.println(ws.toString()); //null pointer exception
        });

    }
}
```

Here is the console output when running activator test

```
[error] Test UserProfileTests.demographicTest failed: java.lang.NullPointerException: null, took 5.291 sec
[error]     at UserProfileTests.demographicTest(UserProfileTests.java:15)
[error]     ...
[error] Failed: Total 4, Failed 1, Errors 0, Passed 3
[error] Failed tests:
[error]     UserProfileTests
[error] (test:test) sbt.TestsFailedException: Tests unsuccessful
[error] Total time: 9 s, completed Jan 21, 2016 11:54:49 AM
```

I'm sure I'm just fundamentally misunderstanding something about dependency injection or how the system works. Any help would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since tests should be extremely focused on just one particular scanario/object, I don't think you need to worry about how to do Dependency Injection for your tests and, instead, just instantiate what you need. Here is a way to instantiate using the application `Injector`:

```
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import play.libs.ws.WSClient;
import play.test.WithServer;

public class UserProfileTests extends WithServer {

    private WSClient ws;

    @Before
    public void injectWs() {
        ws = app.injector().instanceOf(WSClient.class);
    }

    @Test
    public void demographicTest() {
        System.out.println(ws);
    }
}
```

But, of course, you could also just instantiate the `ws` by hand or mock it if you want.

About the `models`, their lifecycle is not handled by Guice and then, there is no direct way to do Dependency Injection at models. You can always find a way to do that, but should you? What will happen if try to load 100 objects from the database and then have to inject a dependency in each of these objects?

Besides the (likely) performance problem, maybe you are also violating [Single Responsibility Principle](http://www.oodesign.com/single-responsibility-principle.html) here and your models are doing to much work.

Comment: Thanks for the informative response. I really appreciate it.

Comment: @marcospereira what should be the proper way to inject the WSClient in general (not in tests, in the app i mean)? I don't think it is a nice design to inject it in a Controller (which is not used) and then have to pass it as a constructor argument to a Service.